# Open file from previous commits without overwriting working copy

Tags: visual-studio-code, commit, source-control

VSCode allows open files from previous commits in comparison editor, is there a way open a file in normal editor, without any comparison?
I'd like to have 2 files opened in 2 tabs, one - current working version and another previous committed version.

I do realize I can copy text from comparison editor into a new file, I'm trying to simplify this process if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example with [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension.

After installing it, on the `Commits` list in `Source Control` tab, you can see icons when you hover over a changed file. Example:

[image: Icons]

If you hover over the 1st `Open File` icon as shown on the screen, you can see that clicking it with <kbd>Alt</kbd> button will open the file at that revision/commit.

Comment: Updated, didn't notice it was an extension.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I had all these tabs inside gitlens section...used "Gitlens Reset View Layout" command and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [Git Graph](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) extension, no need pressing `Alt` key:
[image]

However, unlike GitLens, it prepends commit `id` to the filename, which IMO undesirable, when many tabs are opened the filename might become hidden, another downside is right click menu on the file tab has very limited options.